# how to copy subdocument into the same document

Tags: mongodb

my need is copy one subdocument from a document and insert into the 
same document.But i use forEach and findAndModify it can not insert 
into the same document.

document example:

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("59b5e84d71ab5580d643d070"), 
"modifiedOn" : ISODate("2019-04-03T14:57:22.177+0000"), 
"modifiedBy" : "XXX", 
"createdOn" : ISODate("2017-09-09T16:33:34.464+0000"), 
"createdBy" : "liuyu", 
"channelSales" : [
    {
        "platform" : "amazon", 
        "channel" : "amazon_ca", 
        "saleStatus" : "A", 
        "type" : "", 
        "url" : "", 
        "remark" : "", 
        "isCaught" : "0", 
        "_id" : ObjectId("59b5f86aaa0ee15555a39dc1")
    }, 
    {
        "platform" : "amazon", 
        "channel" : "amazon_uk", 
        "saleStatus" : "A", 
        "type" : "", 
        "url" : "", 
        "remark" : "", 
        "isCaught" : "0", 
        "_id" : ObjectId("59b5f86aaa0ee15555a39dc0")
    }, 
    {
        "platform" : "amazon", 
        "channel" : "amazon_us", 
        "saleStatus" : "A", 
        "type" : "", 
        "url" : "", 
        "remark" : "", 
        "isCaught" : "0", 
        "_id" : ObjectId("59b5f86aaa0ee15555a39dbf")
    }, 
    {
        "platform" : "amazon", 
        "channel" : "amazon_jp", 
        "saleStatus" : "A", 
        "type" : "", 
        "url" : "", 
        "remark" : "", 
        "isCaught" : "0", 
        "_id" : ObjectId("59b5f86aaa0ee15555a39dbe")
    }, 
    {
        "platform" : "amazon", 
        "channel" : "amazon_de", 
        "saleStatus" : "A", 
        "type" : "", 
        "url" : "", 
        "remark" : "", 
        "isCaught" : "0", 
        "_id" : ObjectId("59b5f86aaa0ee15555a39dbd")
    }, 
    {
        "platform" : "amazon", 
        "channel" : "amazon_es", 
        "saleStatus" : "A", 
        "type" : "", 
        "url" : "", 
        "remark" : "", 
        "isCaught" : "0", 
        "_id" : ObjectId("59b5f86aaa0ee15555a39dbc")
    }, 
    {
        "platform" : "amazon", 
        "channel" : "amazon_fr", 
        "saleStatus" : "A", 
        "type" : "", 
        "url" : "", 
        "remark" : "", 
        "isCaught" : "0", 
        "_id" : ObjectId("59b5f86aaa0ee15555a39dbb")
    }, 
    {
        "platform" : "amazon", 
        "channel" : "amazon_it", 
        "saleStatus" : "A", 
        "type" : "", 
        "url" : "", 
        "remark" : "", 
        "isCaught" : "0", 
        "_id" : ObjectId("59b5f86aaa0ee15555a39dba")
    }, 
    {
        "platform" : "ebay", 
        "channel" : "ebay_au", 
        "saleStatus" : "A", 
        "type" : "", 
        "url" : "", 
        "remark" : "", 
        "isCaught" : "0", 
        "_id" : ObjectId("59b5f86aaa0ee15555a39db9")
    }, 
    {
        "platform" : "ebay", 
        "channel" : "ebay_de", 
        "saleStatus" : "A", 
        "type" : "", 
        "url" : "", 
        "remark" : "", 
        "isCaught" : "0", 
        "_id" : ObjectId("59b5f86aaa0ee15555a39db8")
    }, 
    {
        "platform" : "ebay", 
        "channel" : "ebay_es", 
        "saleStatus" : "A", 
        "type" : "", 
        "url" : "", 
        "remark" : "", 
        "isCaught" : "0", 
        "_id" : ObjectId("59b5f86aaa0ee15555a39db7")
    }, 
    {
        "platform" : "ebay", 
        "channel" : "ebay_fr", 
        "saleStatus" : "A", 
        "type" : "", 
        "url" : "", 
        "remark" : "", 
        "isCaught" : "0", 
        "_id" : ObjectId("59b5f86aaa0ee15555a39db6")
    }, 
    {
        "platform" : "ebay", 
        "channel" : "ebay_it", 
        "saleStatus" : "A", 
        "type" : "", 
        "url" : "", 
        "remark" : "", 
        "isCaught" : "0", 
        "_id" : ObjectId("59b5f86aaa0ee15555a39db5")
    }, 
    {
        "platform" : "ebay", 
        "channel" : "ebay_uk", 
        "saleStatus" : "A", 
        "type" : "", 
        "url" : "", 
        "remark" : "", 
        "isCaught" : "0", 
        "_id" : ObjectId("59b5f86aaa0ee15555a39db4")
    }, 
    {
        "platform" : "ebay", 
        "channel" : "ebay_us", 
        "saleStatus" : "A", 
        "type" : "", 
        "url" : "", 
        "remark" : "", 
        "isCaught" : "0", 
        "_id" : ObjectId("59b5f86aaa0ee15555a39db3")
    }, 
    {
        "platform" : "walmart", 
        "channel" : "walmart_us", 
        "saleStatus" : "A", 
        "type" : "", 
        "url" : "", 
        "remark" : "", 
        "isCaught" : "0", 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a4d9de2bb1aee844f03e1a6")
    }, 
    {
        "platform" : "walmart", 
        "channel" : "walmart_ca", 
        "saleStatus" : "A", 
        "type" : "", 
        "url" : "", 
        "remark" : "", 
        "isCaught" : "0", 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a4d9de2bb1aee844f03e1a5")
    }, 
    {
        "platform" : "amazon", 
        "channel" : "amazon_au", 
        "saleStatus" : "T", 
        "type" : "", 
        "url" : "", 
        "remark" : "", 
        "isCaught" : "0", 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5abe095bb1d48d194f6187c0")
    }, 
    {
        "platform" : "amazon", 
        "channel" : "amazon_in", 
        "saleStatus" : "A", 
        "type" : "", 
        "url" : "", 
        "remark" : "", 
        "isCaught" : "0", 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c9af2776f3dcf04491818f2")
    }
], 
"statusLevel" : "", 
"statusType" : "", 
"status" : "A", 
"skuId" : "abc001", 
"__v" : NumberInt(3)
}
```

i want to copy:

```
{
        "platform" : "walmart", 
        "channel" : "walmart_us", 
        "saleStatus" : "A", 
        "type" : "", 
        "url" : "", 
        "remark" : "", 
        "isCaught" : "0", 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a4d9de2bb1aee844f03e1a6")
 }
```

and change the "channel" : "walmart_dsv",the other files is the same like this :

```
{
        "platform" : "walmart", 
        "channel" : "walmart_dsv", 
        "saleStatus" : "A", 
        "type" : "", 
        "url" : "", 
        "remark" : "", 
        "isCaught" : "0", 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a4d9de2bb1aee844f03e1a6")
 }
```

and insert into the same document.

i use this command:

```
db.getCollection("0521").aggregate([
 {$unwind: "$channelSales"},
 {$project: {platform: "$channelSales.platform",
        channel: "$channelSales.channel", 
        saleStatus: "$channelSales.saleStatus",
        type: "$channelSales.type", 
        url: "$channelSales.url", 
        remark: "$channelSales.remark", 
        isCaught: "$channelSales.isCaught", 
        _id: "$channelSales._id"
        }},
 { $match : { "channel" : "amazon_us"} }
 ]).forEach(function(award_team){
if(award_team != null)
{
 db.getCollection("0521").findAndModify(
 {
   query: {_id: award_team._id},
   update: { $push: {channelSales: [ {platform: award_team.platform, channel: "walmart_dsv", saleStatus: award_team.saleStatus, type: award_team.type, url: award_team.url, remark: award_team.remark, isCaught: award_team.isCaught, _id: award_team._id }] } },
   upsert: true,
   });
   }
   });
```

but it is add a new document,what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

You are making a mistake in projection:
You are using sub-document _id to update the main document and you are using option `{upsert: true}` so every time it is inserting a new document in case it does not find _id. 
Update your project as below:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
 {$unwind: "$channelSales"},
 {$project: {
     _id: "$_id",            // Main Document Id 
     platform: "$channelSales.platform",
        channel: "$channelSales.channel", 
        saleStatus: "$channelSales.saleStatus",
        type: "$channelSales.type", 
        url: "$channelSales.url", 
        remark: "$channelSales.remark", 
        isCaught: "$channelSales.isCaught", 
        channelSalesId: "$channelSales._id"     // Sub-Document Id (Caannel Sales Id)
        }},
 { $match : { "channel" : "amazon_us"} }
 ])
```

Now you will get a response like below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b5e84d71ab5580d643d070"),
    "platform" : "amazon",
    "channel" : "amazon_us",
    "saleStatus" : "A",
    "type" : "",
    "url" : "",
    "remark" : "",
    "isCaught" : "0",
    "channelSalesId" : ObjectId("59b5f86aaa0ee15555a39dbf")
}
```

Now you can use "award_team._id" to update Document:

```
db.getCollection("0521").findAndModify(
 {
   query: {_id: award_team._id},
   update: { $push: {channelSales: [ {platform: award_team.platform, channel: "walmart_dsv", saleStatus: award_team.saleStatus, type: award_team.type, url: award_team.url, remark: award_team.remark, isCaught: award_team.isCaught, _id: award_team._id }] } },
   upsert: true,
   });
   }
   });
```

Comment: @UpvotePlease.thanks for you help! But now have a problem. i use this code,it will add a new array in channelSales files, but i want to this is a subdocument in channelSales files